# Accordian select only one panel

Tags: javascript, accordion

I'm using the following code for the type of accordion I'd like to use, but it allows multiple panels to be selected and opened. I would like it to force the other panels closed and only open the one that is selected:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("select").change(function(){
        $(this).find("option:selected").each(function(){
            var optionValue = $(this).attr("value");
            if(optionValue){
                $(".box").not("." + optionValue).hide();
                $("." + optionValue).show();
            } else{
                $(".box").hide();
            }
        });
    }).change();
});
</script>
```

I'm entirely rusty. Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Just close them all when the function first runs and then only open the current target.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work if the option's value always matches the option class. When you do `$('.box').not('.' + optionValue)`, you are searching for all that don't match the class attribute, but `optionValue` comes from the value attribute. I'm assuming the class/value attributes don't match (can't tell without the HTML), so it doesn't hide anything.

Something like this for a selector should work without requiring class to match:

```
$('.box').not('option[value="' + optionValue + '"]').hide();
$('option[value="' + optionValue + '"]').show();
```

Comment: I'm an idiot. I left off the other part of the script:

Comment: <script>
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].onclick = function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (panel.style.maxHeight){
      panel.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
    } 
  }
}
</script>

Comment: All classes are the same for each selection: <button class="accordion">WVCH</button>
<div class="panel">

Comment: @Paul, OK, so I don't see any `<select>` or `<option>` in your HTML, so that's gonna be an issue, since your jQuery selector is looking for `<option>`s. The rest of my answer (targeting with `option[value="' + optionValue + '"]` rather than classes) still applies. You can edit your question to add the additional code.